# Android: Does declaring an intent filter open a door for other apps right away?

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

In Android API [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters.html), it says: "To allow other apps to start your activity, you need to add an intent-filter element in your manifest file for the corresponding  element."

Does that mean, if I declare an intent-filter for my Activity, say A1, then it opens the door right away and other apps can start A1?  If there is no intent-filter declared, then A1 can only be started within the same app. Correct?

Answer (score 2):

Your analysis is correct... for the default behavior.

What really controls whether another app can start your activity is whether or not it is exported. Technically, that is controlled by the `android:exported` flag on your `<activity>` element in the manifest.

The default value of `android:exported` for an `<activity>` is `true` if you have an `<intent-filter>`, `false` otherwise. Since that is what you want 99.44% of the time, you rarely see an `<activity>` have an explicit `android:exported` attribute.